# Estilizar input através de jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou usando o plugin jQuery Validate para validar um formulário. Quando eu declaro as regras na declaração do input o formulário fica vermelho quando não se encaixa nas mesmas, e azul quando se encaixam. Segue um exemplo de declaração do input com regras in-line:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="span4" id="nome" size="16" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" required minlength="2">
</div>
```

Porém, quando faço a validação através de uma função, o formulário não recebe a estilização. Creio que seja algo do Bootstrap ou algo similar. Segue exemplo de validação através da função:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
           $("#idCadastro").validate({
            rules: {
                nome: {
                    required: true, minlength: 2
                }
            messages: {
                nome: {
                    required: "Digite o seu nome", minLength: "O seu nome deve conter, no mínimo, 2 caracteres"
                }
           });
        });
      </script>
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se tem como eu mesmo fazer a estilização usando a validação da função ou algum resultado que ela proporcione.

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura do objeto que você está passando para a função Validate() parece estar errada. rules{},messages{} devem estar separados. Da forma que fez, o objeto message parece ser filho do objeto rules. Sugiro olhar com calma a documentação do pluguin que estiver utilizando e ver como se monta este objeto da forma correta.

Neste link você pode testar e ver a implementação de um JQueryValidate funcionando http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/359/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim, esqueci de colocar aqui uma virgula

Comment: Mas e quanto ao que eu perguntei, há algo a ser feito?

Comment: Fiz o teste no JSfiddle do seu código e implementei algumas correções. veja se funciona [link](https://jsfiddle.net/elpablitos/zfx4LhcL/5/)

Por default o jQueryValidate inputa a classe **error** no input que não passou na validação e **valid** caso passe. Você só precisa de um css para controlar as cores

Comment: Obrigado Pablo, através do seu teste consegui realizar a estilização que queria no meu formulário! =D

Comment: Ok, Anderson. Ajude demais usuários que passarem pela mesma situação que você sinalizando minha resposta como aceita. Abs

Answer (score 0):

Olá, segue o link onde temos um exemplo de utilização do Jquery validate...
[Acessar o Site](http://www.devmedia.com.br/jquery-validate-validando-formularios/26490)